# SwiftJSON parsing { Key: {Key: Value} } case?

Tags: json, swift

Here is my json data :

```
{
    "whois": {
        "queryType": "IPv4",
        "orgID": "ORG572"
    }
}
```

and I want to get "orgID".

I try like this :

```
switch response.result {
case .success(let value):
    let responseJson: JSON = JSON(value)
    let orgID = responseJson["whois"]["orgID"].stringValue
    print(orgID)
case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```

and that 'orgID' in log console is empty.
What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **`Codable`** to parse the `data` instead of using a 3rd party like SwiftyJSON.

**Models:**

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let whois: Whois
}

struct Whois: Codable {
    let queryType, orgID: String
}
```

**Parse** the JSON `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response.whois.orgID)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```